# Sending a message to discord when a certain person posts a video with a bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here is the code I have used

```
const Database = require('easy-json-database')
const db = new Database('./database.json')

const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

const tiktok = require('tiktok-scraper')

client.login('tokenishere')

const resolveID = async () => (await tiktok.getUserProfileInfo('follow.for.afollownocap')).user.id

const sync = async (userID) => {
    const cache = db.get('cache')
    const { collector: newPosts } = await tiktok.user(userID)
    if (newPosts.length === 0) return
    const newPostsSorted = newPosts.sort((a, b) => b.createTime - a.createTime).slice(0, 10)
    if (cache) {
        const post = newPostsSorted.filter((post) => !cache.includes(post.id))[0]
        if (post && (post.createTime > ((Date.now() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000))) {
            const author = post.authorMeta.nickName
            const link = post.webVideoUrl
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(author, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setTitle(post.text)
                .setThumbnail('https://sf-tb-sg.ibytedtos.com/obj/eden-sg/uhtyvueh7nulogpoguhm/tiktok-icon2.png')
                .setImage(post.covers.default)
                .setColor('#00FF00')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(author, client.user.displayAvatarURL())
            client.channels.cache.get('862092037348130868').send(`[@everyone]\n\n**${author} Just posted a new video!\n\nGo check it out: ${link} !**`, embed)
        }
    }
    db.set('cache', newPostsSorted.map((post) => post.id))
}

client.on('ready', async () => {
    client.user.setActivity('online', {
        type: 'WATCHING'
    })
    const userID = await resolveID()
    sync(userID)
    setInterval(() => sync(userID), 120 * 1000)
})
```

I posted a video, it has done nothing. I waited a hour still nothing, no errors, can anyone help me? I tried using different api's but none have worked so far. Yet it should work it does not WHY.
I have been working on this for hours now, it turns on and everything else works, this is not what I mainly use to code so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I strongly advise you to keep your key in an environment variable for security reasons. You can deconstruct it at the top for clean code as well.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { BOT_TOKEN } = process.env;
```

I believe the solution to your question is you are not awaiting the discord login. client.login() returns a promise. You should await that login before executing client-dependant functions.

Lastly, if that didn't work, there isn't much we can do to help without seeing the data you are receiving. If you aren't already, get familiar with your debugger and find out what data you are or, possibly, more importantly, **are not** receiving throughout each step.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `client.login()` to the bottom of the file